# SVG CSS animation issue - weird lines/dots flashing during animation

Tags: css, css-animations, svg-animate

I have created a circle border animation using svg and CSS but there is some weird lines and dots flashing during animation (in chrome).. but it looks fine in firefox. please find the code below and can anyone help me to fix this.. (i have added jsfiddle link in the comment)

[image]

Comment: Please find the code here https://jsfiddle.net/e84rqhgp/

Comment: didn't see any lines or dots in the fiddle. using chrome

Comment: Please try to focus deeply... it will happen for few micro seconds... or just try to zoom the page and check please.